# Include active bootstrap tab in HTML form

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have an HTML form built using bootstrap with two tabs. Some of the form fields change depending on which tab is active. As an example:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="#">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#scheduled">Scheduled</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#event">Event</a></li>
</ul>

  <div class="tab-pane active" id="scheduled">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" id="triggerdate" value="10/24/2016" />
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="event">
    <input id="event" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Event" />
 </div>
</form>
```

I would like a way to include the active tab as an input in the form.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bootstrap's callback events to update a hidden input:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  // e.target // newly activated tab
  // e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
  $('input.whatever').val(e.target.id); // id property not tested, but you get the idea
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events

And yes, do provide the progress of your attempt next time.

Comment: Apologies for the vague question, but that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks